# Differences in nc (netcat) options on Ubuntu vs RedHat

Tags: ubuntu, redhat-enterprise-linux, netcat

```bash
nc -q -1 local host ${PORT} ${CMD}
```

In Ubuntu, `nc` may be used as above, with the `-q` option. See [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/nc_openbsd.1.html).

- **`-q`** after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit. If seconds is negative, wait forever.

However, this option is not available in Redhat 5. See [manpage](http://www.gb.nrao.edu/php/man2html/man.php?topic=nc). How do I achieve the equivalent of `nc -q` in RedHat 5?

Comment: What version of netcat are you using?  Did you compile from source, or install using your package manager? You might want to try compiling [netcat from source](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/download.php), or attempting to compile the Ubuntu version on your Redhat machine.  Also, it would be helpful to explain why you need this behaviour (specifically why you need to wait X seconds after EOF), as it might help to suggest alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want that option for?  If you explain the use case, maybe we can come up with an alternative.

For example, maybe this is sufficient?

```bash
while 1; do
    nc localhost ${PORT}
done
```

I think the [linux.die.net man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) is from RedHat Enterprise Linux 5, but not 100% sure.